# How to get integer for two characters in python

Tags: python, string, integer

```
a = "a26lsdm3684"
```

How can I get an integer with value of 26(a[1] and a[2])? If I write int(a[1) or int (a[2]) it just gives me integer of one character. What should I write when I want integer with value of 26 and store it in variable b?

Comment: Use the plus `+` operator?

Comment: `int(a[1:3])` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Slice out the two characters, then convert:

```
b = int(a[1:3])  # Slices are exclusive on the end index, so you need to go to 3 to get 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get substrings out of the string and convert that to int, as long as you know the exact indexes

```py
a = "a26lsdm3684"

substring_of_a = a[1:3]
number = int(substring_of_a)

print(number, type(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it.
Use [Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/967621), as pointed out by *jasonharper* and *ShadowRanger*.
Or use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) to find the first stretch of digits.
Or use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split on non-digits and find the 2nd element (the first one is an empty string at the beginning).

```
import re

a = "a26lsdm3684"

print(int(a[1:3]))
print(int((re.findall(r'\d+', a))[0]))
print(int((re.split(r'\D+', a))[1]))
# 26
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more sustainable if you want multiple numbers from the same string:

```
def get_numbers(input_string):
    i = 0
    buffer = ""
    out_list = []
    while i < len(input_string):
        if input_string[i].isdigit():
            buffer = buffer + input_string[i]
        else:
            if buffer:
                out_list.append(int(buffer))
            buffer = ""
        i = i + 1
    if buffer:
        out_list.append(int(buffer))

    return out_list

a = "a26lsdm3684"
print(get_numbers(a))
```

output:

```
[26, 3684]
```

Comment: If you want multiple numbers at arbitrary offsets, you'd just use `re.findall(r'\d+', input_string)` to pull them all at once without a complicated parsing loop.

Comment: Agreed. You can use regex. I however don't like to reach for it in stack overflow for these simple questions since regex will most likely go over OP's head. A for loop can be better understood. albeit complicated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all the numeric parts in your string, and say put them in a list, you may do something like:

```
from re import finditer
a = "a26lsdm3684"
s=[int(m.group(0)) for m in finditer(r'\d+', a)] ##[26, 3684]
```